# Analog input dependent on samples quantity used in averaging

Tags: adc, noise

I found this issue using arduino but IMO this relates more to electronic eng.
I use pin0 without any pull-up/pull-down/connection.

Simplified code:

```
if (samplesQty >= 5000){
  Serial.println(buffer/samplesQty);
  buffer = samplesQty = 0;
} else { 
  buffer += analogRead(0);
  samplesQty++;
}
```

The question is why do I get value ~450 (out of 1024 max) if I take 2 samples, ~390 if there is about 800 samples and 25 if there is 5700 samples?

I'm definetly not taking all these samples consequently, i.e. if there is 800 samples, I do 1 ms delay after *samplesQty++*, all samples are taken in less than 1 second.

Thank you in advance.

p.s.: I know how to get steady zero while 'in the air', the question is kind of theoretical.

Comment: Do you have anything connected to the input pin? If not, then likely what is happening is that you are starting out with a small amount of charge on the floating pin. The way the A/D converter on that chip works is that it connects a capacitor to the pin to sample the voltage. Each time it does that, you are bleeding off a little bit of the initial charge, so the voltage is going to drop a little with each sample.

Comment: What's the definition of the buffer variable? Is it "int buffer;" or "long buffer;"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the analog to digital sample circuit on that chip looks like...

[image]

When you first start off, the pin happens will likely have some residual charge on it, which causes a voltage to appear. Each time you sample, a little bit of that charge is bled off to charge the internal capacitor. As you bleed of more charge with each subsequent sample, the closer the voltage asymptotically gets to Vcc/2.

On the opposing side, that input circuit is has very high input impedance so it only takes a little charge to develop a voltage on the pin. If you connect a dangling wire to the pin, the wire will become an antenna and the voltage that you read on the pin will depend on the EMF in the area. In most places with AC power, the dominant EMF frequency will be 50/60Hz (depending on where you live) coming from the power lines.

There is another possibility- without seeing the rest of your code, it is possible that `buffer` is overflowing. If, for example, `buffer` is only an `unsigned int`, then eventually it will grow to be bigger than 65536 (the largest value an unsigned in can hold) and will wrap around to a lower value. Make sure `buffer` can hold at least 1024 * 5000.

Comment: I tried to quickly remove residual charge from the input (connecting to the gnd) but looks like it reappears; with 1 samples/sec it reminds an exponent and gets saturated in ~6 seconds (samples). 

buffer is a long int, i know about overflow but ty anyway.

Comment: Have you tried just taking a sample every, say, 100ms and printing it- just to keep the program as simple as possible and narrow down any possible interactions? If so, do you see the value start high and then slowly go down asymptotically to 0? Does is go back up when you reset the MPU, or when you touch the board?

Comment: I've just tried as you advised, value stays in 356-430 with avg 400.5 and reminds a sinus. After a quick grounding it raises: 0-69-110-143-167-186-205-..-430 and so on.

Comment: I just checked using a Arduino Uno and [this code](https://gist.github.com/bigjosh/41dec494662dd7b3e3bf). In my very cold and dry NYC apartment, I see the values converge to about 300 when I perterb it by touching the input pin and either ground or Vcc at the same time. If I connect a dangling wire to the pin, I can move the value across most of the full range by waving my hand around it mystically. My guess is that the specific pattern of bleed is highly dependent on the environment, including humidity and stray EMFs. Try taking your board someplace different and see if anything changes.

Comment: What is the frequency of the wave? 50/60Hz perhaps? That would make sense. Make sure you are sampling at a high enough speed that it would not be aliased.

Comment: One more funny moment: with 26cm wire i can get pretty clear 20hz signal varying from 0 to 1023. Moreover, the highest value that I can achieve connecting it to arduino pin with 'HIGH' value is 1021.

Comment: Yep - you made a radio! The wire is acting like an antenna and picking up any EMF around it. Put the whole circuit inside a Faraday cage (a metal box) and that signal should go away (or be greatly reduced depending on how good the box is).

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation :) I know that a wire acts like an antenna, but I don't get what may be the source of 20Hz signal and why it's more powerful (1023) comparing to straight Vcc-ADC connection (1021-1022). Do you have any idea?

Comment: My bad.. it's a clear 50Hz utility frequency. Thank you for your time.